# Why is it not possible to call method if a class explicitely extends Object?

Tags: typescript

When I have a class in Typescript that explicitely extends Object, then trying to call an object method of that class fails:

```
class Example extends Object {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public getHello() : string {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

let greeter = new Example();
alert(greeter.getHello());
```

Error: `greeter.getHello is not a function`. Why is that? If I remove the `extends`-clause and the `super()` call, then it suddenly works.

My problem is that the code is autogenerated from a customized JSweet version, and we only transpile some part of the codebase. Classes in the class hierarchy that should not be transpiled are simply mapped to `Object`, because the `extends` cannot be easily removed without changing JSweet heavily.

Comment: Do you happen to have the transpiled code that the typescript becomes? If I write this as ES6 instead of typescript by removing the 'public' and the ' : string' inside `public getHello() : string {`, everything works. So this has to be something that typescript messes up during transpilation.

Comment: @Shilly you can try that in the typescript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ This is an interesting behavior indeed.

Comment: @Shilly: I indeed used typescriptlang.org/play to write and transpile this minimal working example. In the meantime, J.T. Crowder has pasted the transpiled code in his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56022356/2181399

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could argue that this is a bug in TypeScript. Not a high-priority one, probably, but... :-)

It's because `Object` ignores the `this` it's called with, and returns a new, blank object. The way TypeScript compiles that code (when targeting ES5 environments), it ends up calling `Object` like this in `Example`:

```
function Example() {
    return Object.call(this) || this;
}
```

The result of `Object.call(this)` is a new object, as though you did `{}`.

So the solution is...don't do that. :-)

> My problem is that the code is autogenerated from a customized JSweet version, and we only transpile some part of the codebase. Classes in the class hierarchy that should not be transpiled are simply mapped to Object, because the extends cannot be easily removed without changing JSweet heavily.

Ouch. If you can target ES2015+, the problem goes away as this only relates to the version TypeScript creates for ES5 and earlier. If you can't, I'm afraid it sounds like you'll want to file an issue on [the TypeScript issues list](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) and perhaps do a pull request with a fix. (I went looking for an existing report and didn't find one.) This is slightly different from extending other built-ins (`Error`, `Array`) in that there's a very simple solution: Just ignore the `extends` clause.

Or, as you mentioned in a comment, you could have a dummy class that doesn't do anything, like:

```
class FauxObject { }
```

and then use that instead of `Object` (`class Example extends FauxObject`).

---

Just for detail's sake, the full compiled version is this, the call to `Object` is marked by `******`:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Example = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Example, _super);
    function Example() {
        return _super.call(this) || this;             // ******
    }
    Example.prototype.getHello = function () {
        return "Hello";
    };
    return Example;
}(Object));
var greeter = new Example();
alert(greeter.getHello());
```

`_super` is `Object` in your case.

Comment: Oh. So, you're telling me that no one ever tried to actually extend `Object`? That's weird.

Comment: @briosheje - Or that they tried it, it didn't work, and they shrugged and removed `extends Object` since it doesn't do anything useful anyway. :-)

Comment: Well, it's true that it doesn't, but I would expect many people coming from other typed languages to actually believe that extending `Object` is somewhat a right choice. That's weird :D.

Comment: @briosheje - I don't know of a single language using similar syntax where you would normally include `extends Object`. All classes extend `Object` intrinsically in the ones I know (Java and C#, primarily).

Comment: I don't know either, but since in javascript objects are everywhere, I think this could lead someone to actually extend the Object type when starting to use typescript. Of couse, as you said, it's usually intrinsical (I'm used to C# and Java as well), but it's still confusing, in that case. What I'm wondering is whether someone ever noticed that, since it's actually an unintended behavior (to me) :P. On the other hand, however, the typescript examples never ever shows any snippet where `Object` is extended, so...

Comment: Can you elaborate the statement "This is slightly different from extending other built-ins (Error, Array) in that there's a very simple solution: Just ignore the extends clause."? Does extending other built-ins behave differently? I only need a dummy class that I can use as a mapping target (`Foo extends Dummy`).

Comment: @hunger - The Dummy class solution makes sense! Re your question: You can't properly extend `Error` or `Array` in ES5 and earlier, because they also ignore `this` when they're called, so `Error.call(this)` and `Array.call(this)` don't work. As far as I know, TypeScript makes no attempt to handle that, probably because it's imposssible (in ES5 and earlier) to do properly. But `extends Object` could be supported by just ignoring it entirely and outputting what it would output if it weren't there (whereas you can't just ignore `extends Error` or `extends Array`).

Comment: I ended up accepting this answer late (used the dummy class approach), as the other workaround caused more trouble further down the road during the transpilation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After filing a [bug-report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31308) I was hinted to [a FAQ entry that addresses extending typescript built-ins](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work):

> In ES2015, constructors which return an object implicitly substitute the value of this for any callers of super(...). It is necessary for generated constructor code to capture any potential return value of super(...) and replace it with this.
>
> As a result, subclassing Error, Array, and others may no longer work as expected. This is due to the fact that constructor functions for Error, Array, and the like use ECMAScript 6's new.target to adjust the prototype chain; however, there is no way to ensure a value for new.target when invoking a constructor in ECMAScript 5. Other downlevel compilers generally have the same limitation by default.

The explanation is similar to [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56022356/2181399), plus they recommend another additional workaround:

> As a recommendation, you can manually adjust the prototype immediately after any super(...) calls.

Which in my case would be to add `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Example.prototype);` into the constructor (or convince JSweet to do so).

**But**:

> Unfortunately, these workarounds will not work on **Internet Explorer 10** and prior. One can manually copy methods from the prototype onto the instance itself (i.e. FooError.prototype onto this), but the prototype chain itself cannot be fixed.

EDIT: I ended up using this workaround as I found it easier to implement in our JSweet project.

EDIT 2: This workaround had other drawbacks, so we went ahead and used a dummy class as briefly described in the accepted answer.